# Punctuation within parenthesis

Tags: punctuation

How would I go about putting a period within a parenthesis sentence:

(Code is subject to change. Refer to tips below.)

Do I put a period after "below" or do I remove it:

(Code is subject to change. Refer to tips below)

Comment: The standard approach in most styles is to put the period within the parentheses if the parentheses contain one or more whole sentences (as in your example) but outside the parentheses if they contain only a word or phrase not intended as a complete sentence (as I demonstrate here at the end of this comment).

Comment: Why would you remove the period? What is your justification for doing so? Why are you removing it at the end of one sentence but not the other?